# Can't add VideoJS component to ModalDialog

Tags: video.js

I want to add up-next modal to my video.js player just like YouTube.

So I created a button component and `appendChild()`.

But `content()` of modal dialog is empty! Of course, modal dialog in browser is empty too.

`contentEl()` has the html I expected, but it don't affect to DOM.

```js
// create next button component
const _getForwardBtn = (player) => {
  const customForwardBtn = _createVjsComponent(player, 'forwardButton')
  customForwardBtn.el().innerHTML =
  `<button>Go Forward</button>
  `
  const goNext = () => {
    alert('forward button clicked') // debug
  }
  customForwardBtn.on('click', goForward)
  return customForwardBtn
}
const forwardBtn = _getForwardBtn(player)

// create modal component
const ModalDialog = videojs.getComponent('ModalDialog')
const modal = new ModalDialog(player, {
  name: 'upNextModal'
})

// add forward-button into modal dialog
modal.addChild(forwardBtn)

// add modal dialog into player
player.addChild(modal)

console.log(modal.content()) // -> Empty!
console.log(modal.contentEl().outerHTML) -> '<div class"vjs-modal-dialog">...'
```

How do I fix it?

---

P.S.

I tried to set `content()` to html directly and got the HTML I expected, but **click event won't fire**.

```
const forwardBtn = _getForwardBtn(player)

// create modal component
const ModalDialog = videojs.getComponent('ModalDialog')
const modal = new ModalDialog(player, {
  name: 'upNextModal'
})

// add forward-button into modal dialog
modal.addChild(forwardBtn)

// set modal content directly
const contentEl = document.createElement('div')
contentEl.innerHTML = modal.contentEl().innerHTML
modal.content(contentEl)
```